# How to sort array with numbers, alphanumeric, alphabets in JavaScript (only JS) as in Excel?

Tags: javascript

Currently I am working on sorting for my app. User may enter values in my table as shown in my array. So I am trying to sort exactly as in Excel. But it is not working as expected.

Note: I don't want to use any external library.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PraveenGopal/mzLvp346/)

```
function sortAlphaNum(a, b) {
     var reA = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
     var reN = /[^0-9]/g;
     var aA = a.replace(reA, "");
     var bA = b.replace(reA, "");
    if (aA === bA) {
      var aN = parseInt(a.replace(reN, ""), 10);
      var bN = parseInt(b.replace(reN, ""), 10);
      return aN === bN ? 0 : aN > bN ? 1 : -1;
   } else {
    return aA > bA ? 1 : -1;
   }
}
```

My array : [1, 1000, 3qwewqe, 500sfsd, erew3432, dsfds, 450, 332sadas4234, aqeqw, zkjsfkjs, 2, 3]

Expected output as in Excel:

[image]

Comment: Do you need to only sort strings, or you need also convert "numbers" to numbers (as in Excel)?

Comment: Exactlay as in Excel. Numbers to numbers

Comment: @Anton I hope ur answer works as in Excel i guess

Comment: I've updated my answer . You can use `arr = arr.map((item) => isNaN(item) ? item : +item);` to convert strings to numbers if possible.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = ["1", "1000", "3qwewqe", "500sfsd", "erew3432", "dsfds", "450", "332sadas4234", "aqeqw", "zkjsfkjs", "2", "3", "324", "4sizfiu34324"];

arr.sort(function sortAlphaNum(a, b) {
  if (isNaN(a) && !isNaN(b)) return 1; // strings after numbers
  if (!isNaN(a) && isNaN(b)) return -1; // numbers before strings
  if (isNaN(a)) return a > b ? 1 : -1; // string compare
  return +a - +b; // number compare
});

// Use this line if you want to convert "string numbers" to numbers:
arr = arr.map((item) => isNaN(item) ? item : +item);

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr=["1", "1000", "3qwewqe", "500sfsd", "erew3432", "dsfds", "450", "332sadas4234", "aqeqw", "zkjsfkjs", "2", "3", "324","4sizfiu34324"];
var reA = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
var reN = /[^0-9]/g;

arr.sort((a,b) => {
    let inta = parseInt(a);
    let intb = parseInt(b);
    if (!isNaN(inta) && isNaN(intb)) return -1;
    if (isNaN(inta) && !isNaN(intb)) return 1;
    if (!isNaN(inta) && !isNaN(intb)) return inta-intb;
    return a.localeCompare(b);
});

document.getElementById("log").value=arr.join("\n");
```

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="log"></textarea>
```